# autocomplete jquery multiple fields onchange or tab event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

So, I have this jquery code in my php page that gets data from a mysql table:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tracking_num").autocomplete({
        source: "func/populate.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
            $('#particulars').val(ui.item.particulars);
            $('#remarks').val(ui.item.remarks);
            $('#location').val(ui.item.location);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm challenged to get the data immediately into the fields without selecting it from the drop down box. Do you guys have any idea how to do it? Here's my the func/populate.php file:

```
$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_document WHERE tracking_number = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch) ) {
    $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
    $row_array['particulars'] = $row['particulars'];
    $row_array['remarks'] = $row['remarks'];
    $row_array['location'] = $row['location'];
    $row_array['value'] = $row['tracking_number'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

mysql_close();

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: can you show the html part for the `select` please ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
$(function() {
    $("#tracking_num").autocomplete({
        source: "func/populate.php",
        minLength: 2,
        create: function(event, ui) {
            $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
            $('#particulars').val(ui.item.particulars);
            $('#remarks').val(ui.item.remarks);
            $('#location').val(ui.item.location);
        }
    });
});
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Stan. I'll explain a little more. It's a jquery autocomplete problem I have. The dropdown appears when you type something in this textbox:
`<input type = "text" name = "tracking_num" id = "tracking_num" placeholder = "Enter the Tracking No">`
The dropdown lists numbers from a mysql database. When you choose a number from the dropdown, it will fill other textboxes below it. The thing is, I'm not liking the 'choosing from the dropdown' part since most tracking numbers matches my db. It would be better if I just click on Tab and the data will be filled to the textboxes.